# Java API for changing Tile Caching settings in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, java, geoserver-rest-api

I am looking for Java APIs to change the highlighted part in the image in the Tile Caching tab in the configuration of a layer.

This is the tab.

[image]

This is the filter function that I am interested in.

[image]

This is what I want to achieve.

[image]

I have searched through the methods offered by GeoSolutions at the following link.
https://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/gsman/apidocs/index-all.html
I cannot find specific APIs for the section I am interested in. Do you know if there are libraries that offer methods to achieve my purpose from Java code rather than from an interface?

Answer (score 1):

These changes are controlled by the REST-API and as such don't need a specific library, just the JAVA URL class to GET and POST the XML files you need to change.

Comment: Thanks!!! Do you know where I could find some examples?

Comment: the GeoServer manual - https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/index.html#rest